# Swift: Moving the rearrange button to top-left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView that I can rearrange and expand single items. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the rearrange button is always in the middle of the item. So when an item is expanded it overlays some controls. Is it possible to have this reanrange button always in the right corner? So it has the same position as the non expanded items and it does not move when the item gets expanded?

Here is something that I have found on other threads but it doesn't work. The position stays the same but it is now disabled.

```
        cell.subviews.forEach { (view) in
        if (view.description.range(of: "UITableViewCellReorderControl") != nil) {
            let resizedGripView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
            resizedGripView.addSubview(view)
            cell.addSubview(resizedGripView)
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: cell.frame.size.width - cell.frame.size.width, y:  1)
            resizedGripView.transform = transform
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a better solution. Never add views directly to the cell. Always add your views to the cell's `contentView`. The `contentView` is sized properly based on the cell's decorations.

Comment: yes but in my case I want the cell's decorator (the rearrange button) to overlap the view. I want it to have it in the top-right of my contentView but not in the middle-right

Comment: There's no API to move the standard reorder icon. If you want custom reordering, use your own icon placed where you want it and use drag-and-drop for reordering (iOS 11+).

Comment: Does that mean I can't use tableView's moveRowAt function? And is it only usable for iOS 11+?

Comment: You can still use `UITableView moveSection(_:toSection:)`. But if you implement custom drag-and-drop, you wouldn't implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods related to the older standard row reordering.